# How to extract middle portion of filename to use it in output file name while doing pipeline?

Tags: unix, terminal, command-line

I have several filenames such as xxxxxx_1111_xxxxxx_xxxxxxxxx.vcf where only the "1111" part varies. I need to run awk on it to extract parts of these files, and when I do that I want to rename the output depending on the name of the file. My code looks like this:

```
for i in *_xxxxxx_xxxxxxxxx.vcf
do 
    awk 'substr($0,1,3)=="zzz"' $i > ${i%??}_edited.vcf
done
```

I essentially want to just extract the 1111 and make sure the output file is called **1111.edited_vcf**.

Also the length varies... its not always 4 chars.

Comment: You can cut on the `_` in your filenames and keep the second field for the 1111.  Then if 1111 is longer than 4 chars it will still work.

Comment: I am aware I could do that, I just don't know how I would implement while trying to do above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f -name "*_xxxxxx_xxxxxxxxx.vcf" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
    awk 'substr($0,1,3)=="zzz"' "$file" > "$(echo "$file" | cut -d'_' -f2)"_edited.vcf
done
```

- The `find` with `while` is from https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001
- parameter expansion could probably used in lieu of `cut`, but I am no expert with that syntax.